# Making a MediaController Navigable with D-Pad

Tags: google-tv

I'm working on a custom media controller.   I have it so that the Surface View correctly shows and hides the view. The view is populated with a SeekerBar and about for ImageButtons.  However, I can't figure out how to make the D-Pad navigate to these items.

If I use the synaptic touchpad on the remote, I can select the buttons and the seekerbar, but can't use the D-PAD to get to these items.   Do I need to catch the events when the view is shown. Is there a good example for google tv on a custom media controller implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you will need to catch the key code events and manage the focused items accordingly to make that work.

Comment: One of the issues I'm seeing is that the MediaController view doesn't seem to be gaining focus.  I put a break point in my dispatchKeyEvent in the MediaController where I added the D-Pad navigation and it is never hit.

Comment: Accepting as it gives me what I need, I just need to debug further why my overlays aren't gaining focus.

Comment: I believe you can have the layout request focus and have your activity be an onKeyListener and then bubble down the focus/selection handlers to your surface view elements.

Comment: Thanks I need to do some more experimenting with things.

Comment: Found the actual problem.  In my custom MediaController I needed to call setFocusable(true).  By default the MediaController itself is not focusable.  Once I set this, D-Pad navigation events started firing.